# How can I modify this batch script's directory?

Tags: batch-file

This batch script creates a text file of a list of files in its own directory, sans file extensions. However, I would like it to create a list of another directory's files instead. How could I modify it to attain those results?

```
@echo off
cd %1
if exist filelisting.txt del filelisting.txt
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /A-D /B /O:GEN') do echo %%~nj >> filelisting.txt
```

Comment: Try this single line batch file `@(FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR/B/A-D/OE "C:\Location"') DO @ECHO %%~nA)>"filelisting.txt"`

Comment: I got it to work, however I notice that there is an empty line at the end of the file every time... Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: You can move `>>filelisting.txt` to the left of `echo %%~nj`.

Comment: 1. Are you aware that the location can be passed as a command line argument to your batch file? 2. `cd %1` should read `cd /D "%~1"`; alternatively, change your `dir` command line to `dir /B /A:-D /O:EN "%~1"`. 3. Follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906523/how-can-i-modify-this-batch-scripts-directory#comment76790413_44906523).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

```
@echo off
cd %1
if exist filelisting.txt del filelisting.txt
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir "c:\Location\*" /A-D /B /O:GEN') do echo %%~nj >> filelisting.txt
```

Comment: This example doesn't use the most appropriate `dir` options and echo's a single space after each file name in the listing output.